# Cisco ASA Port Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

We have a Cisco 5510 router and I can succesfully configure port forwarding from the external interface to a port on an internal address. If I access this from the outside it works correctly, but if I access this from the inside it does not work.

How do I make the internal requests resolve correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are not trying to access the outside from the inside and loop back around which would be silly because it circumvents the basic usage of the ASA or any firewall device just manually add the entries in your dns server.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to enable it as I have not used this model, however this is due to NAT Loopback and is usual behaviour when it is disabled. Look in the manual or settings and see anywhere if you have the option to enable it.

I am trying to find the option for you now... if I find how to do it, I will edit this answer.

Edit - still not found it, but someone on the Cisco forums asked a similar question and the response was to use a feature called "DNS doctoring"

Answer (score 0):

Standard for Cisco equipment.  When I had Cisco and was hosting my own domains as well, I just setup BIND for split-zone DNS.  Queries from the outside would resolve to the outside interface and queries from the inside then resolve to the inside interface.  Thus, going direct instead of trying to bounce off the firewall.